# How to join each value of first array with each value of second array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose we have two arrays

```
var arrayOne = [21.03.2016, 22.03.2016, 23.03.2016]
var arrayTwo = [23.45, 34.45, 25.76]
```

How can we join it so that it becomes

```
var joinedResultOfOneandTwo = [[21.03.2016, 23.45], 
                               [22.03.2016, 34.45],
                               [23.03.2016, 25.76]]
```

**Note** It is important that we do not change the type of variables both of them should be numbers.

This is what I have tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
            var clintonValues = arrayOne[i].concat(arrayTwo[i])

          }
```

returns:

**TypeError: arrayOne[i].concat is not a function**

Comment: Syntax Errors. No Attempts. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Use map. `arrayOne.map((item, index) => [item, arrayTwo[index]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example

```js
var arrayOne = ['21.03.2016', '22.03.2016', '23.03.2016']
var arrayTwo = ['23.45', '34.45', '25.76']
var joinedResultOfOneandTwo = [];

for (i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
  joinedResultOfOneandTwo.push([arrayOne[i], arrayTwo[i]]);
}

console.log(joinedResultOfOneandTwo);
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try .concat? It will join two arrays into one
`var arrayOne = [21.03.2016, 22.03.2016, 23.03.2016];
var arrayTwo = [23.45, 34.45, 25.76];
arrayOne.concat(arrayTwo);//join arrayTwo into arrayOne`

Comment: `concat()` would combine the arrays into a single dimensional array, but user has requested a 2D array.

Comment: That's correct, my bad.